# WiX / Burn: Set Uninstall screen information

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I have created an MSI file to install one of my programs using WiX 3.7.  I have a single file that I created to contain company information that is displayed in Control Panel -> Programs and Features as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>

  <Property Id="ARPCOMMENTS" Value="My Service" />
  <Property Id="ARPCONTACT" Value="My Company, LLC" />
  <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="DC.ico" />
  <Property Id="ARPHELPLINK" Value="http://www.mycompany.com" />
  <Property Id="ARPREADME" Value=" " />
  <Property Id="ARPURLINFOABOUT" Value="http://www.mycompany.com" />
  <Property Id="ARPURLUPDATEINFO" Value=" " />
  <Property Id="ARPHELPTELEPHONE" Value="888 888 8888" />
  <Property Id="ARPAUTHORIZEDCDFPREFIX" Value=" " />

  <Icon Id="DC.ico" SourceFile="Resources\DC.ico" />

</Include>
```

I now have to create a boot strapper using Burn to include Crystal Reports & C++ 2005 Redist.  In the Control Panel -> Programs and Features the information from the MSI (the Property items from above) is NOT shown.  I now just have a couple very generic pieces of information.  Is there a way to include the information above in a Burn file so it shows up in the Control Panel -> Programs and Features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Bundle element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/bundle.html) has attributes that let you specify ARP properties.